# Understanding struct of tree

Tags: c

I have this path tree struct:

```
    typedef struct treeNodeListCell;

typedef struct _treeNode
{
    char* position;
    treeNodeListCell* next_possible_positions; 
} treeNode;

typedef struct _treeNodeListCell
{
    treeNode* node;
    struct _treeNodeListCell* next;
} treeNodeListCell;

typedef struct _pathTree
{
    treeNode* head;
} pathTree;
```

and when i want to initialize a new tree i have this error

```
pathTree initTree(char* start)
{
    pathTree T;
    T.head = (treeNode*)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
    T.head->position = start;
    T.head->next_possible_positions = NULL;
}
```

visual studio wants me to add * in to-  `T.head->position;` line, to be written like this:
`*(t.head)->position= start;`

have no idea why, maybe i didn't understand the struct build as it should be.

thank you!

Comment: can you paste the exact compiler error on VS?

Comment: Also confirm that the code you are showing is exactly the code you compiled to get that error.

Comment: The syntax `*(t.head)->position` would be valid if `t.head` were a pointer to a pointer. Check to see if somewhere you have a definition (either a typedef or a #define) that makes `treeNode` a pointer. Something like `typedef struct ... * treeNode` or `#define treeNode TN*` or something like that.

Comment: Of course you need to add `return T;` at the end of your function.

Comment: I don't know why, but when you copy the string then t.head->position worked. But I didn't understand why I can't put the address in it.... Thanks for all the helpers!